# How to import library in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm new with C++.

Here's my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(HelloWorld)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(HelloWorld ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I tried `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/websocketpp)` (`target_include_directories` too), but it didn't work. The library is in project folder. Should I put it somewhere else?

I got this:

> C:\Users\Marczak\ClionProjects\HelloWorld\main.cpp:2:23: fatal error: websocketpp: No such file or directory`.

`websocketpp` is header only library.

How to import it properly?

Comment: `include_directories` ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/websocketpp)` but it didn't work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The library is in my project folder. Should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] of what you did please. As is your question is too vague. `include_directories` defintitely is the way to go for header only libraries.

Comment: Not related to your question, but in cmake 3.5+ instead of setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` you may prefer [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_compile_options.html) or [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_compile_options.html). Even better to manage C++11 is [target_compile_features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_compile_features.html) which provides a fine grained control and add compile flags automatically

Comment: @wasthishelpful CMakeLists.txt was automatically generated by CLion IDE. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) to point at the directory the header files are in (in this case, directory of the library), and you include the specific headers you need ([See the examples](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/tree/master/examples)), not the entire directory.

[echo_client example](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/echo_client/echo_client.cpp) includes `#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>`. You may want to start with that.

Comment: Can you show me an example of `target_include_directories`?

Comment: @SzymonMarczak There's one in the CMake documentation section I linked - you pass it a target, you tell it whether it's `PUBLIC`/`PRIVATE`/`INTERFACE` (which doesn't matter in your case since you write a program, not a library, so `PRIVATE` should be enough), and you pass it a path.

Comment: Oh, thanks. It works! I tried `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})` instead of `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/websocketpp)` too, and it worked.